# wsdl2java code generation for lists of custom objects

Tags: apache-axis, wsdl2java

I would like to know if the tool "wsdl2java" (Axis2) is able to generate stubs that support getting list of custom ojects.

For instance, if I have a WS that have the following method:

```
public List<Device> getDevices(){
//...
}
```

Where `Device` is a custom class...

This tool can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the return data type of my Web Service to an array because of that:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-coding/index.html

And I had to do some changes (some namespaces) to the generated stub (I used ADB)...
I changed that because it was giving me an `ADBException: Unexpected subelement ...`